# is it possible to run step in TFS pipeline based on some condition

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In multi step TFS pipeline is it possible to add conditions for a step when it should run ? (something similar to Control Options -> Run this task -> custom conditions at tasks level)

Comment: What do you mean "step"? Do you use TFS on-prem or Azure DevOps?

Comment: We use on-prem TFS, "step" i meant a deployment block (stage/step) in pipeline.

Comment: I don't think is possible. in which condition you want to run the stage?

Comment: there is some variable, based on its value want decide to run/skip a stage.

Comment: you can put the custom conditions on the agent job, the stage will start the release but will skip all tasks if the agent job custom conditions fail

Comment: if i understood correctly at Agent Phase in the demands we put variable equals condition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182087/discussion-between-reddysekhar-gaduputi-and-shayki-abramczyk).

Answer (score 0):

to add conditional for a Azure devops pipeline step you can use [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)

Like below:

```
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)\doc'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(docfxPath)\_site_pdf\'
        Contents: '*.pdf'
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(docfxPath)\_site'
      condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['pdfName'], ''))
```

`condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['pdfName'], ''))` will make copy file task to be executed only if `pdfName` variable has value (is not empty string) and job has not failed.